# Let $A\in M_n(C)$. If $A$ is not a scalar matrix, then prove that there exists an invertible matrix $S$ such that $S^{-1}AS=B$ and $B_{11}=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

Let $A\in M_n(C)$. If $A$ is not a scalar matrix, then prove that there exists an invertible matrix $S$ such that $S^{-1}AS=B$ and $B_{11}=0$

I have no idea on how to approach this problem. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint 1:** You can assume without loss of generality that $A$ is diagonal/Jordan form (why?).

**Hint 2:** If $A=\begin{bmatrix} a & 0 \\ 0&b \end{bmatrix}$ with $a \neq b$ can you find such an $S$?

This should tell you exactly what to do when $A$ is diagonal or a Jordan form, with not all eigenvalues equal.

Comment: I have not yet studied Jordan forms, if you could please elaborate your answer. otherwise, I'll come back to your answer after I have sufficient knowledge of it.